# AngularJS - Passing Controller Name To Service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

I have a selection of controllers:

```
Controller1
Controller2
Controller3
```

I also have a service which all of my Controllers call. At the moment at the top of every Controller ive created a scope declaring the Controller name:

```
$scope.ControllerName = 'Page1Controller';
```

I then pass this scope into the service:

```
$scope.$parent.Description = serviceMydata.getDescription($scope.ControllerName).toString();
```

Is there a way to not have to declare `$scope.ControllerName`?

My service:

```
app.service('serviceMydata', function(){

    return {
        getDescription: function(ControllerName) {
            return [
                mapData[ControllerName]
            ];
        }
    }
});

var mapData = {
    Page1Controller : 'Data to insert when on Page1',
    Page2Controller : 'Data to insert when on Page2',
    Page3Controller : 'Data to insert when on Page3',
    Page4Controller : 'Data to insert when on Page4',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this when you declare your controllers:

```
(function(){

    var ctrlName = 'MainCtrl'

    app.controller(ctrlName, function($scope, service) {
        myService.fn(ctrlName);
    });

})();
```

Afaik, there isn't a simple way of doing it through angular and I don't see a reason to try.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've added some more of my service, are you able to see the purpose of it? Essentially to return a set of values based on the Controller

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the name of your controller inside a closure in the service:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.service('myservicefactory', function () {
    return {
        create: function (name) {
            var controllerName = name;
            return {
                getDescription: function () {
                    console.log(controllerName);
                }
            };
        }
    };
});

app.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', 'myservicefactory', function ($scope, myservicefactory) {
    $scope.service = myservicefactory.create('myctrl');
    $scope.callService = function () {
        $scope.service.getDescription();
    };
}]);
app.controller('myctrl2', ['$scope', 'myservicefactory', function ($scope, myservicefactory) {
    $scope.service = myservicefactory.create('myctrl2');
    $scope.callService = function () {
        $scope.service.getDescription();
    };
}]);
```

Yes, you would have to instantiate your service and provide the controller name or whatever, but after that, it's captured inside your service. Here's a fiddle that demonstrates: http://jsfiddle.net/29wtqeyz/1/.

I don't think you want something more tightly coupled then that: keep in mind that your service should not be coupled to its consumer.